# Pivot_longer of multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to tidy a data frame of identified peptide sequences in several samples:

`Sample_Elu_HN`, `Sample_LW_HN`, `Sample_Elu_HM`, `Sample_LW_HM`, `Sample_Elu_M1`, `Sample_LW_M1`, `Sample_Elu_M2`, `Sample_LW_M2`, `Sample_Elu_N1`, `Sample_LW_N1`, `Sample_Elu_N2`, `Sample_LW_N2`, and `Control_Preload_None`.

The data frame contains info on each peptide, including their abundance in each sample, and how confident its identification was.

```
names <- c("Sequence", "Modifications", "Master Protein Accessions","Missed Cleavages",
           "Abundance: Mean: Control, None, Preload","Abundance: SD: Control, None, Preload","Abundance: CV: Control, None, Preload",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, HM, Elu","Abundance: SD: Sample, HM, Elu","Abundance: CV: Sample, HM, Elu",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, HN, Elu","Abundance: SD: Sample, HN, Elu","Abundance: CV: Sample, HN, Elu",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, M1, Elu","Abundance: SD: Sample, M1, Elu","Abundance: CV: Sample, M1, Elu",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, M2, Elu","Abundance: SD: Sample, M2, Elu","Abundance: CV: Sample, M2, Elu",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, N1, Elu","Abundance: SD: Sample, N1, Elu","Abundance: CV: Sample, N1, Elu",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, N2, Elu","Abundance: SD: Sample, N2, Elu","Abundance: CV: Sample, N2, Elu",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, HM, LW","Abundance: SD: Sample, HM, LW","Abundance: CV: Sample, HM, LW",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, HN, LW","Abundance: SD: Sample, HN, LW","Abundance: CV: Sample, HN, LW",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, M1, LW","Abundance: SD: Sample, M1, LW","Abundance: CV: Sample, M1, LW",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, M2, LW","Abundance: SD: Sample, M2, LW","Abundance: CV: Sample, M2, LW",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, N1, LW","Abundance: SD: Sample, N1, LW","Abundance: CV: Sample, N1, LW",
           "Abundance: Mean: Sample, N2, LW","Abundance: SD: Sample, N2, LW","Abundance: CV: Sample, N2, LW",
           "Found in Sample Group: Control, Preload, None","Found in Sample Group: Sample, Elu, HM",
           "Found in Sample Group: Sample, Elu, HN","Found in Sample Group: Sample, Elu, M1",
           "Found in Sample Group: Sample, Elu, M2","Found in Sample Group: Sample, Elu, N1",
           "Found in Sample Group: Sample, Elu, N2","Found in Sample Group: Sample, LW, HM",
           "Found in Sample Group: Sample, LW, HN","Found in Sample Group: Sample, LW, M1",
           "Found in Sample Group: Sample, LW, M2","Found in Sample Group: Sample, LW, N1",
           "Found in Sample Group: Sample, LW, N2")
peptide1 <- c("FQSEEQQQTEDELQDK","1xPhospho [S3(100)]","P02666",0,591079706.5,129831141.4,21.96508186,92078374.7,5559797.773,6.038114585,130764801.6,11101742.04,8.489854991,304661843.6,89701289.78,29.44290257,100024065.8,174405.3367,0.174363375,20777445.26,7953029.115,38.27722329,43696929.72,10030935.24,22.95569805,496031039,260945694.4,52.60672697,111323285.3,32961482.23,29.60879402,329268465.6,243189584.2,73.85753864,478737037.1,153121463.4,31.98446151,701372889.6,20000942.58,2.851684585,847417746,84344510.23,9.953120599,"High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High","Found","High","High","High")
peptide2 <- c("HPGDFGADAQGAMTK","1xPhospho [H1(100)]","P68082",0,295017576,49088902.73,16.63931464,2845912.875,709262.9265,24.92215882,3659951.5,215619.485,5.891320828,41946172,301640.4391,0.719113151,9336196.75,1507110.776,16.14266298,1469308.375,434213.7682,29.55225572,1607320,498424.3673,31.00965379,191151516,137956380.3,72.17121954,236416096,97608884.31,41.28690303,119327816,55998433.41,46.92823123,152802424,9555841.041,6.253723462,147086456,33874815.85,23.03054732,255244232,75472108.91,29.56858548,"High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High","Not Found","High","Not Found","High")
peptide3 <- c("IEKFQSEEQQQTEDELQDK","","P02666",1,75099003,12104439.14,16.11797582,18015945.88,6770542.657,37.58083369,7913736.75,4197999.975,53.04700053,46005954.5,8581332.638,18.65265645,14313846.5,4426286.925,30.92311298,5085692.75,528187.9059,10.38576123,7676983.313,3681526.619,47.95538129,24546758.5,13126407.14,53.47511419,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,9098671.051,22.39353163,31170934,NA,NA,"High","High","High","High","High","High","High","Not Found","Not Found","Not Found","High","Not Found","High")

example.data <- as.data.frame(rbind(peptide1, peptide2, peptide3))
colnames(example.data) <- names
example.data
```

What I want is to gather the columns `"Abundance: Mean: ..."`, `"Abundance: SD: ..."`, `"Abundance: CV:..."` and `"Found in Sample Group: ..."` into `"Mean"`, `"SD"`, `"CV"` and `"Found"`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
library(tidyr)
example.tidy <- pivot_longer(example.data, cols = c(str_which(colnames(example.data), "Abundance: [^F]"), str_which(colnames(example.data), "Found in Sample Group")),
                             names_to = c(".value", "Sample", "Polymer", "Fraction"), names_pattern = "(.*): (.*), (.*), (.*)")
```

However, it separates in different rows the Mean, SD and CV values from the Found values, leaving a lot of NA values...

What is it that needs to be fixed so that all values from all variables are contained in the same row?

Thank you for your help, as always!

Comment: Can you please give an example of the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change those names you want to stack into a single pattern.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example.data %>%
  rename_with(~ sub(".+?:\\s", "", .), starts_with("Abundance")) %>%
  rename_with(~ sub(".+:(.+),(.+),(.+)", "Found:\\1,\\3,\\2", .), starts_with("Found")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-(1:4), names_to = c(".value", "Set"), names_sep = ":\\s") %>%
  separate(Set, c("Sample", "Polymer", "Fraction"))

# # A tibble: 39 x 11
#    Sequence       Modifications      `Master Protein Accessi… `Missed Cleavages` Sample Polymer Fraction Mean      SD        CV        Found
#    <chr>          <chr>              <chr>                    <chr>              <chr>  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>
#  1 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Contr… None    Preload  59107970… 12983114… 21.96508… High 
#  2 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample HM      Elu      92078374… 5559797.… 6.038114… High 
#  3 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample HN      Elu      13076480… 11101742… 8.489854… High 
#  4 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample M1      Elu      30466184… 89701289… 29.44290… High 
#  5 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample M2      Elu      10002406… 174405.3… 0.174363… High 
#  6 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample N1      Elu      20777445… 7953029.… 38.27722… High 
#  7 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample N2      Elu      43696929… 10030935… 22.95569… High 
#  8 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample HM      LW       496031039 26094569… 52.60672… High 
#  9 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample HN      LW       11132328… 32961482… 29.60879… High 
# 10 FQSEEQQQTEDEL… 1xPhospho [S3(100… P02666                   0                  Sample M1      LW       32926846… 24318958… 73.85753… Found
# # … with 29 more rows
```

There is a trap in your data. Those columns starting with `Found` should be renamed to match the pattern of other columns. E.g.

```
Found in Sample Group: Sample, Elu, HM
```

should be renamed as

```
Found in Sample Group: Sample, HM, Elu
```

and so on.

Comment: Hi Darren! My R studio can't find the function rename_with(). Also, I can see from your result table that it still does not provide what I want. The "Found" variable does not have the "High" or "Not Found" values, just NA.

Comment: @IgnacioA.D. I think I found the problem. Please check my edit.

Comment: @IgnacioA.D. update `dplyr` version to `1.0.0` and `rename_with()` will work.

Comment: Hi Darren! Thank you for pointing out the trap! I did not see it! It was copied directly from the software results and I assumed it was the same pattern in all variables. I will rename them and try again with the updated dplyr.

Comment: @IgnacioA.D. I have done the rename with my second line of code, so you don't need to change your original data. Good luck.